# useState method doesn't allow access to outside variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Wondering why the following doesn't work:

```
  const onChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setEmails(prevEmails => ({
      ...prevEmails,
      reports: e.target.value
    }))
  }
```

Event 'e' variable console.logs but when used in setEmails it's saying can't find value of null?
Exact error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is prevEmails defined?, I think it is not necessary to add it as variable function.

Comment: @MayraNavarro React will preserve this state between re-renders. useState returns a pair: the current state value and a function that lets you update it.  You can learn more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook

Comment: what I mean : setEmails({...prevEmails, reports: e.target.value}), no anonymous function needed.

Comment: that would cause a "not defined" error.  @MayraNavarro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either save the value to another variable, or use `e.persist()`:

```
const onChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    let myValue = e.target.value;
    setEmails(prevEmails => ({
        ...prevEmails,
        reports: myValue
    }))
}
```

This is because in React uses [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) for performance reasons. From the **[event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)** section of the docs:

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent` object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.